# Reference to array of foreign keys

Tags: sql, associations, one-to-many, varray

Let's say I have a table `T` - its every row has a key (assume `TID` column). Now I have a second table `A` where for each row I'd like to have a list of values from `TID`. How could I achive this?

I thought about creating `VARRAY` of values from `T` and putting it in `A` but I somehow feel it's not a right way to go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one row in T can belong to more than one row in A, the [normal way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is to create a link table:

```
create table A_TO_T 
    (
    TID foreign key references T(TID), 
    AID foreign key references A(AID),
    primary key (TID, AID)
    );
```

A link table is also called a [junction or cross-reference table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29).

If one row in T can only belong to one row in A, you can add a foreign key to the T table:

```
alter table T add
    AID foreign key references A(AID);
```

Comment: huh, I knew how it works and still I didn't think about it. such a simple solution. thanks!